# number of segment is too large for given radius

Tags: sketchup

What can I do for this error?

> Number of segments is too large for the given angle and radius.

I decreased this segment value by ctrl - after that I can't revolute the arc portion.

After that I can see the arc segments are not united, they are all separated automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Number of segments is too large for the given angle and radius.

> This happens when the arc is very small and the segments would need to be too small to draw. Solution is to either lower the number of segments (type the number of segments you want before drawing the arc), or scaling the model up, drawing the arc, then returning the model to its original scale.

And

> I would recommend scaling your entire model up by 100, draw your arc(s), then scale your model by 0.01 to return it to its original scale.

Source [Number of segments is too large for given angle and radius - Technical Problems / SketchUp - SketchUp Community](https://forums.sketchup.com/t/number-of-segments-is-too-large-for-given-angle-and-radius/47278/2)